# How do I bind an ArrayList to a PreparedStatement in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, arraylist, prepared-statement

I was wondering if there was a way to bind an ArrayList (or any kind of List, for that matter) to a PreparedStatement which will eventually be used to access an Oracle database.  I found:

[PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/alternatives-for-java-sql-preparedstatement-in-clause-issue)

And that seems similar to my issue, but this question is more specific: I'd like to bind an ArrayList to a PreparedStatement to be used in Oracle, if it is possible, how is this accomplished?

Comment: In what capacity? What does your statement (with placeholders) look like? I doubt there's a general solution to this since 1) the length of List will vary and 2) the number of placeholders in your statement likely will not. Also, not all Lists are ordered.

Comment: Matt, all objects that implement java.util.List provide a get(int) operation that retrieves the object at the specified index.  It also provides an iterator.  Both of these are non-optional: the order may be odd, but an order exists. So all java.util.List implementations *are* ordered...

Comment: ...and, in Java, List typically refers to the java.util.List interface contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't bind a List to a single parameter in a prepared statement.

Generate SQL with the a parameter marker for each element in the list, for example:

```
SELECT NAME FROM ITEM WHERE ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Even though you'll generate a new statement for each query, I'd still recommend using a `PreparedStatement`. If your list contains `String` instances, you'll get the necessary escaping to protect from SQL injection.

But even if it's a safe type, like `Integer` objects, some drivers or middleware can cache `PreparedStatements`, and return a cached instance if the same form is requested. Of course, some testing would be necessary. If your lists vary widely in size, you'll have many different statements, and a poorly-implemented cache might not be prepared to handle so many.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but it seems like you do have to generate a "question-mark string" and append it to your general SQL statement.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind it directly.  There is a way to pass an array as a parameter.  I have no idea what you want to do with it on the database side so this may not help you.

Basically, you have to create a nested table type in the database; build a Java object based on that type, containing the data from your array; and pass that as the parameter.

If you created these objects in the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_nested_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
CREATE TABLE my_table (a  my_nested_table) NESTED TABLE a STORE AS my_table_a;
```

Then you can write Java code like this:

```
String[] insertvalues = { "a", "b", "c" };
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES( ? )");
ARRAY insertParameter = new ARRAY( a_desc, conn, insertvalues );
p.setArray( 1, insertParameter );
p.execute();
```

The results in Oracle look like this:

```
dev> select * from my_table;

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY_NESTED_TABLE('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging by the answer to that one, especially the comments to my wrong answer in that question, you can't.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#996857.

Comment: That's a useful link, but it wasn't what I was going for.  Sorry.