# Fetch data using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

This is my query

```
select id,name,address from emp_details where gender = ?
```

Input : Female , Male

In this usually I need to fetch only Female data or only Male data
But some times I need to fetch both Female and Male data using the same query..

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: You want to use something like the in clause which is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Comment: An in clause wouldn't help. The number of parameters would be 1 in the first case, and 2 in the second case. So the SQL query would be different.

Comment: how do you know ? when you need both data?

Answer (score 2):

just invert the query:

```
select id,name,address from emp_details where gender <> ?
```

and specify "male" for getting females, "female" for getting males, and "whatever" for getting both.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same query, no, it's not possible. Use a query without any where clause to do that:

```
select id,name,address from emp_details
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the in-clause

```
where gender in ?
```

and as parameter a array of string

```
new String[]{"m","f"}
```

Comment: Works for me, what a db do you use?

Comment: Oracle, for instance. But I wonder how it can work on yours. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303218/how-do-i-bind-an-arraylist-to-a-preparedstatement-in-oracle for example. See also http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html which has been created by Spring to allow named parameters AND list expansion into multiple parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id , name , address
FROM emp_details 
WHERE gender IN (?,?);
```

Male of Female only => set for both ? the same value

[PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String gender="Female ";

    String sql = "select id,name,address from emp_details";

    if(gender!=null && !"".equals(gender))

     {      
        sql+=" where gender = ?";

     }
```