# Remove specific characters from a String in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following query:

```
select *from activo where id_oficina in(22,23) and id categoría = 'in(1,2)'
```

How can I remove the "=" character and the single quotes?

I'm working with kendo Ui and I did not know what can be removed manually.

Comment: `string.replaceAll("[=']", "")`

Comment: i does not work, my code line is:
filter.replaceAll("[=']","");

Comment: Are you assigning the new value back to filter? `filter = filter.replaceAll("[=']","");`

Comment: Not, only add new String:
String filter1 = filter.remplaceAll("[=']","");
filter = filter1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replaceAll` suggested by @Andy Turner works:

```
String string = "select *from activo where id_oficina in(22,23) and id categoría = 'in(1,2)'";
string = string.replaceAll("[=']", "");
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Know nothing of Kendo, but it appears that you're trying to enter 'in(1,2)' in a field and then have that substituted into the query statement, instead of just entering a single value.

First off, should be using JDBC bind variables, somehow, any SQL statement created by doing string concatenation is ripe with security holes.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection

Second, you can't bind values for an IN the same way as a single value.  Now, you could always have an IN clause and sometimes you'll bind just a single value.  This has been addressed before:
[How do I bind an ArrayList to a PreparedStatement in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303218/how-do-i-bind-an-arraylist-to-a-preparedstatement-in-oracle)