# How to set list of parameters on prepared statement?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

i have a list of names e.g.:

```
List<String> names = ...
names.add('charles');
...
```

and a statement:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = 
  conn.prepareStatement('select * from person where name in ( ? )');
```

how to do the following:

```
stmt.setParameterList(1,names);
```

Is there a workaround? can someone explain why this method is missing?

using: java, postgresql, jdbc3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no clean way to do this simply by setting a list on the `PreparedStatement` that I know of.

Write code that constructs the SQL statement (or better replaces a single ? or similar token) with the appropriate number of questions marks (the same number as in your list) and then iterate over your list setting the parameter for each.

Answer (score 23):

This question is very old, but nobody has suggested using [setArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray-int-java.sql.Array-)

This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240302/573057

Comment: setArray won't work with MySQL or JavaDB as they don't support the ARRAY data type in SQL.  See the note at the top of:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html

Comment: @TigerC10 good point ... curiosity piqued re: Java in-memory dB - Derby (JavaDB) doesn't support but both [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type) and [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_array) do.

Answer (score 2):

this method is missing due to **type erasure** the parameter type of the List is lost at runtime. Therefore the need to add several methods arires: `setIntParameters`, `setLongParameters`, `setObjectParameters`, etc

Comment: if there is a add method for every data type, why isn't there a 'addList' method for every datatype too? (e.g. addStringList(...))

Comment: this is the point, the Statement interface is already bloated even without counting list variants

Comment: Type erasure is not a good reason, there could be
setArrayParameter(int pos, Object[] params)

Answer (score 1):

For postgres 9 I have used this approach:

```
 jdbcTemplate.query(getEmployeeReport(), new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(from.getTime()));
            ps.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(to.getTime()));
            StringBuilder ids = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < branchIds.length; i++) {
                ids.append(branchIds[i]);
                if (i < branchIds.length - 1) {
                    ids.append(",");
                }
            }
            // third param is inside IN clause
            // Use Types.OTHER avoid type check while executing query  
            ps.setObject(3, ids.toString(), **Types.OTHER**);
        }
    }, new PersonalReportMapper());
```

Comment: Does this really work for `in (?)`? What does the actual statement look like once it's issued to the server?

Comment: You want to avoid concatenation of string values in your JDBC code, as that might easily lead to SQL injection bugs. -1

Answer (score 0):

In case the questions' meaning is to set several params in a single call...

Because the type validation is already defined in a higher level, I think the only need is for [setObject(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-).

Thus, a utility method can be used:

```
public static void addParams(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object... params) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        Object param = params[i];
        preparedStatement.setObject(i+1, param);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SqlUtils.addParams(preparedStatement, 1, '2', 3d);
```

Feel free converting this to a Java 8 lambda :)

Comment: setObject passing a List<String> throws an exception with Oracle driver

Answer (score -1):

I was reviewing code this morning and one of my colleagues had a different approach, just pass the parameter using `setString("name1','name2','name3")`.

**Note:** I skipped the single quote at the beginning and end because these are going to be added by the `setString`.

Comment: For constant strings, it might be acceptable. For user input, it is a nice example of code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: This absolutely should not work.  If it does, there's a bug in your JDBC driver.  `setString` deals with the apostrophes, so that you actually get the `String` that you passed.  Had your colleague tested their code?

Answer (score -1):

After examining various solutions in different forums and not finding a good solution, I feel the below hack I came up with, is the easiest to follow and code. Note however that this doesn't use prepared query but gets the work done anyway:

Example: Suppose you have a list of parameters to pass in the 'IN' clause. Just put a dummy String inside the 'IN' clause, say, "PARAM" do denote the list of parameters that will be coming in the place of this dummy String.

```
    select * from TABLE_A where ATTR IN (PARAM);
```

You can collect all the parameters into a single String variable in your Java code. This can be done as follows:

```
    String param1 = "X";
    String param2 = "Y";
    String param1 = param1.append(",").append(param2);
```

You can append all your parameters separated by commas into a single String variable, 'param1', in our case.

After collecting all the parameters into a single String you can just replace the dummy text in your query, i.e., "PARAM" in this case, with the parameter String, i.e., param1. Here is what you need to do:

```
    String query = query.replaceFirst("PARAM",param1); where we have the value of query as 

    query = "select * from TABLE_A where ATTR IN (PARAM)";
```

You can now execute your query using the executeQuery() method. Just make sure that you don't have the word "PARAM" in your query anywhere. You can use a combination of special characters and alphabets instead of the word "PARAM" in order to make sure that there is no possibility of such a word coming in the query. Hope you got the solution.

Comment: You do know that this might lead to SQL injections?

Answer (score -3):

Other method :

```
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    // first param inside IN clause with myList values
    ps.setObject(1 , myList.toArray(), 2003); // 2003=array in java.sql.Types
}
```

Comment: Please give some explanation to your code