# Passing list of IDs to SQL Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

This code:

```
ids = "1245, 4526, 7689, 8001";
jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (?)", new Object[] { ids });
```

throws the following exception:

> (...) nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

How do I pass the list of IDs to the above sql statement?

Comment: Not sure what jdbcTemplate's type is in your case but you may want to check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305240/how-to-set-list-of-parameters-on-prepared-statement

Comment: A placeholder is a single value, not a list of values.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong.You can't pass list to single arguement.

Try this.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?)", new Object[] { 1245, 4526, 7689, 8001});
```

Comment: The first one won't work, a placeholder is a single value not a list, unless JDBC template (or the specific driver) does some magic.

Comment: Yupe so i change my answer.