# Pass a single parameter and a parameter List with Spring's JDBCTemplate (namedJDBCTemplate)

Tags: spring-jdbc

How to code such a simple SQL with Spring JDBC ?

```
UPDATE tableA SET column1 = var1 WHERE column1 IN (var2, var3, ...);
```

where var1 is dynamic variable and var2, var3, ... - dynamic variable list.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `IN` , you can do like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE tableA SET column1 = ? WHERE column1 =? ");
ps.setString(1, var1);
ps.setString(2, var2);
```

And about how to deal with `In` I hope [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause) may give you some clue.

After some search, I also found this question may help you:

[PreparedStatement with list of parameters in a IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause)

[How to set list of parameters on prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305240/how-to-set-list-of-parameters-on-prepared-statement)

[PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)