# How to pass multiple search values in where condition

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I connected to database in my java program. I have a situation where I need to pass filter values dynamically, filter values depends of others parts of java code

Example query: select * from table1 where id in (dynamic and multiple)?

How to pass these dynamic and multiple values using Java connection.

Comment: I have a list of a values that I need to pass to my where condition, how can pass those values. Pls help me resolve

Comment: you could create in clause as string and append to the query.

Comment: Select * from emp where id in(list(0),list(1),list(2));

Comment: Does the above query works,? Is there any limit for number of parameters?

Comment: if its a int, it will work, if this is string you have to enclose it with single quotes

Comment: Ok . Any limit for number of parameters that I could pass?

Comment: yes, depends on the database you are using

Comment: If you have a large in clause put that in a table and use it as subquery like select * from table1 where id in (select col from INCLAUSE_TAB)

Comment: If you are using PreparedStatement, there are lots of duplicate/similar queries which exist check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305240/how-to-set-list-of-parameters-on-prepared-statement
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String query =  "select * from emp where id in(##)";
```

create the in clause like this

```
String inClause = "'abcd', 'cedf', '1234'";

String finalQuery = query.replace("##", inClause );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iBatis, you can try with below sql query:-

```
<select id="table1Result" resultMap="table1Map">
select * from table1 where id in <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="(" separator=","        close=")"</select>
```

While calling it from java, pass a List of ids.