# PreparedStatement - not binding all the parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring-JDBC to execute the SQL and fetch the results.

```
 SELECT 
       SUM(spend) total_sum   
    FROM TABLE_NAME  
       WHERE   
       sup_id = ?  AND    
      ( ( YEAR = ? AND period IN ( ? ) )   OR     
      ( YEAR = ? AND period IN(?)))
```

And the bind variables are passed as:

```
final Object[] paramMap = { "1234", "2010",
                "'01_JAN','02_FEB','03_MAR'", "2009", "'11_NOV','12_DEC'" };

final List<LeadTimeDto> query = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, paramMap,
                new RowMapper<LeadTimeDto>() {
                    @Override
                    public LeadTimeDto mapRow(final ResultSet resultSet,
                            final int arg1) throws SQLException {
                        final LeadTimeDto leadTimeDto = new LeadTimeDto();
                        final String string = resultSet.getString("total_sum");
                        System.out.println("ltime = " + string);
                        leadTimeDto.setLeadTime(string);
                        return leadTimeDto;
                    }
                });
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. I've the problem with the binding of the THIRD parameter.
If I write the value of the third parameter in the query itself as below it is working.

```
 SELECT 
       SUM(spend) total_sum   
    FROM TABLE_NAME  
       WHERE   
       sup_id = ?  AND    
      ( ( YEAR = ? AND period IN ( '01_JAN','02_FEB','03_MAR' ) )   OR     
      ( YEAR = ? AND period IN(?)))
```

If it is the problem with quotes(') then FIFTH param should have also been the issue. But it is binding fine.

I've tried using getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() as well both with Map and Bean, but no luck.

Comment: did you get an exception ? if yes post it pls

Comment: No errors. just that the records are not fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using prepared statement parameters for IN clause is not legal as far as I know.
See the following article, which describes some alternatives:

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Comment: @Schneider: thank you :) it worked. Looks like am not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/alternatives-for-java-sql-preparedstatement-in-clause-issue