# pass variable from java to SQL IN clause

Tags: java, sql

I have to format a string such that it can be sent to the IN clause of SQL.
String s = ('A','B').This string s shud be passed from java to sql.How can this be done

Comment: You should know how to do it as you ask a lot of similar questions in the past.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/alternatives-for-java-sql-preparedstatement-in-clause-issue

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this many times and to the best of my knowledge each element in the set needs to be a separate parameter:

```
String sql = "select * from customer where city in (?, ?, ?)";
PrepareStatement p = ..;
p.setString("Mumbai");
p.setString("Pune");
p.setString("Bangalore");
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply create the SQL statement and append the string to it

```
String sql = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE a IN "+s;
```

Now you can create a SQL Statement from this string. 
A better way may be to use prepared statements...

Comment: Avoid creating queries with concatenation. It's dangerous. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: PreparedStatements and IN clauses don't play together very well.