# How do I declare a String array in a Java SQL declareParameter call?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Simplified for illustrative purposes:

```
String[] filter = {"foo", "bar"};
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ?";
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.ARRAY));
```

This doesn't work when I execute it (I get a `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Invalid parameter binding(s).` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC doesn't support this kind of query officially and SQL Server doesn't either as far as I know. This topic has been discussed on SO many times and several workarounds have been proposed:

- [What is the best approach using JDBC for parameterizing an IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)
- [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)
- [pass variable from java to SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721873/pass-variable-from-java-to-sql-in-clause)
- [Trouble with PreparedStatement that uses union of selects query and IN CLAUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595773/trouble-with-preparedstatement-that-uses-union-of-selects-query-and-in-clause)

You can probably find many more as it is indeed a very relevant yet still open topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about MS SQL Server. But such a code wouldn't work on oracle DB. In oracle, we cannot pass a java array to an IN clause. The way to work around that limitation is to construct a PL/SQL function that converts a list of strings into a table, something like stringToTable. Then pass a concatenated string as a parameter.

Again, this answer is applicable for Oracle DB; It might not work on MS SQL server.

Comment: It can be done in Oracle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198856/pass-array-to-oracle-procedure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155146/problem-using-oracle-parameters-in-select-in/6155801#6155801.

Comment: I did not say that it cannot be done in oracle. I just said that you cannot directly pass a java array into a PL?SQL array without doing some intermediate processing or mapping. Your links provide one way to do it. The answer I gave is another way that I have done in my code.