# What are the max number of allowable parameters per database provider type?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, sqlite, postgresql

There is a limit of 2,100 parameters which can be passed to a Sql Server query i.e. via ADO.Net, but what are the documented limits for other common databases used by .Net developers - in particular I'm interested in:

- Oracle 10g/11g
- MySql
- PostgreSql
- Sqlite

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Oracle: 64,000. [Source](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/e_limits.htm#LNPLS018)

MySQL:

- By default, there is no limit. The MySQL "text protocol" requires that the .NET client library substitute all parameters before sending the command text to the server; there is no server-side limit that can be enforced, and the client has no limit (other than available memory).
- If using "prepared statements" by calling `MySqlCommand.Prepare()` (and specifying `IgnorePrepare=false` in the connection string), then there is a limit of 65,535 parameters (because `num_params` has to fit in [two bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-prepare-response.html#packet-COM_STMT_PREPARE_OK)).

PostgreSql: EDIT: 34464 for a query and 100 for a function as per Magnus Hagander's answer (Answer copied here to provide a single point of reference)

SqlLite: 999 (SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to 999, but can be lowered at runtime) - And for functions default is 100 parameters. [See section 9 Of Run-time limits documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: The answer for PostgreSQL refers to 7.2, which was current about 10 years ago. The correct answer for a recent version of PostgreSQL is 100. But that refers to the number of parameters in a *function call*, not to how many you can bind in the client interface. I'm unsure what the .net driver limit is for pg, though, and I don't have a .net environment around, so i can't comment on the actual answer, unfortunately :(

Comment: Thank you Magnus. I've added your response into the answer. I confess to knowing very little about PostreSql!

Comment: Fair enoguh - I changed it to 100 and not 16 though, because that's what was in my answer. The answer still responds to a different question for the other databases, though...

Comment: with regard to sqlite, the limit of the number of parameters defaults to _999_; this is stated under _Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement_ at http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: I have successfully added 100,000 parameters to a `MySqlCommand` using the [official ADO.NET connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), so the limit is greater than 65,536. Be aware that the `MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add` method uses an O(n) algorithm (as of v6.5.4), so adding 100,000 parameters does take almost two minutes (adding _n_ parameters is O(n^2) overall).

Comment: It may be worth noting that your database client/driver may impact this also. For example, it seems that the JDBC driver for PostgreSql limits the maximum number of parameters to 32,767 (2 ** 15 - 1): https://blog.makk.es/postgresql-parameter-limitation.html

Comment: With postgresql 9.6.3 I can do a single insert with 65535 parameters without problems. 65536+ parameters fails.

Answer (score 17):

In jOOQ, we've worked around these limitations by inlining bind values once we reach the relevant number per vendor. [The numbers are documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-inline-threshold/). Not all numbers are necessarily the correct ones according to vendor documentation, we've discovered them empirically by trial and error through JDBC. They are (without tying them to a specific version):

- Ingres : 1024
- Microsoft Access : 768
- Oracle : 32767
- PostgreSQL : 32767
- SQLite : 999
- SQL Server : 2100 (depending on the version)
- Sybase ASE : 2000

Other databases do not seem to have any limitations - at least we've not discovered them yet (haven't been looking far beyond 100000, though).

Comment: Could you elaborate on inlining? what exactly do you mean/how does it work?

Comment: @TimBüthe: normally, jOOQ generated SQL statements produce bind variables, e.g. `SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN (?, ?, ..., ?)`. But when a limit is reached (or client code requests it, explicitly), the generated SQL will contain "inline" values instead, e.g. `SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN (1, 2, ..., 53675)`

Comment: How about ORA-01795 limiting to 1000? This seems to contradict your number here.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel: That's an entirely different limitation, namely the number of elements in an `IN` list, which is also handled by jOOQ by splitting the `IN` list using `OR` predicates. This limitation is independent of whether bind variables are used or not.

Comment: For IBM DB2 v11 limit is `32767` as provided in product documentation: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sql-xml-limits

Comment: @Axinet: Where exactly does it say that?

Comment: @LukasEder to be clear: 32767 is the limit for host variables, not for inlined variables. It was quite hard to find, so I left it here for future reference. (Table 8. Database Manager Limits, SQL, "Maximum number of host variable references in a dynamic SQL statement")

Answer (score 7):

The PostgreSQL wire protocol uses 16-bit integers for count of parameters in the bind message (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html).

Thus the PostgreSQL protocol doesn't allow over 65535 parameters for a single statement. This is, OK to send a single ado.net command with two statements, each of which has 65535 parameters.

Comment: Current protocol parameters are here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html. The same limit.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer for PostgreSQL appears to be 34464, when talking about bound parameters to a query. The response 100 is still correct for number of parameters to a function.

Comment: With postgresql 9.6.3 I can do a single insert with 65535 parameters without problems. 65536+ parameters fails.

Comment: This answer is too old.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the MySQL question actually has two answers. The prepared statement protocol defines a signed 2 byte short to describe the number of parameters that will be retrieved from the server. The client firstly calls [COM_STMT_PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-prepare.html), for which it receives a [COM_STMT_PREPARE response](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-prepare-response.html) if successful.

The documentation for the response states:

> If num_params > 0 more packets will follow:
>
> Parameter Definition Block
>
> - `num_params` * `Protocol::ColumnDefinition`
> - `EOF_Packet`

Given that `num_params` can only be a maximum of 2^16 (signed short), it would follow that this is the limit of parameters and as my company has a custom MySQL driver we chose to follow this rule when implementing it and an exception is thrown if the limit is exceeded.

However, `COM_STMT_PREPARE` does not actually return an error if you send more than this number of parameters. The value of `num_params` is actually just 2^16 and more parameters will follow afterwards. I'm not sure if this is a bug but the protocol documentation does not describe this behaviour.

So long as you have a way on your client-side to know the number of parameters (`client_num_params` if you will), you could implement your MySQL client in such a way that it expects to see `client_num_params` x `Protocol::ColumnDefinition`. You could also watch for `EOF_Packet` but that's only actually sent if `CLIENT_DEPRECATE_EOF` is not enabled.

It's also interesting to note that there's a reserved byte after `num_params`, indicating that the protocol designers probably wanted the option to make this a 24-bit number, allowing about 8.3 million parameters. This would also require an extra client capability flag.

To summarise:

- The client/server protocol documentation seems to indicate that the maximum number of parameters could be 32768
- The server doesn't seem to care if you send more but this doesn't appear to be documented and it might not be supported in future releases. I very much doubt this would happen though as this would break multiple drivers including Oracle's own ADO.NET Connector.