# Efficient Bulk INSERT/COPY into table from HashMap

Tags: java, postgresql

**Task:**

Given this HashMap structure: `Map<String, Map<String, String>> mainMap = new HashMap<>()`

I want to `INSERT` or `COPY` each *value* of the *inner* `Map` into its own cell in my database.

- The `size()` of `mainMap` if 50,000.
- The `size()` of the inner `Map` is 50.
- The table to be inserted into has 50 columns.
- Each column's header is the key for the inner `Map`.

**EDIT:** Originally the user uploads a large spreadsheet with 35 of the 50 columns. I then "cleanse" that data with various formatting, and I add my own 15 new  pairs into the innerMap for each `mainMap` entry. I can't directly `COPY` from the user's source file to my database without cleansing/formatting/adding.

Once I'm done iterating the spreadsheet and building `mainMap`, that's when I need to insert into my database table efficiently.

**Research:**

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres) that `COPY` is the best approach to initially bulk populate a table, however I'm stuck on whether my requirements warrant that command.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583841/4594511) states that Postgres has a Prepared Statement parameter limit of 34464 for a query.

I'm assuming I need 50 x 50,000 = 2,500,000 parameters in total. 
This equals out to ~ 73 individual queries!

**Question:**

- Is `COPY` the proper approach here instead of all these parameters?
- If so, do I convert the `HashMap` values into a `.sql` file, save it on disk on my web app server, and then reference that in my `COPY` command, and then delete the temp file? Or can I directly pass a concatenated `String` into it, without risking SQL injection?

This command will be happening often, hence the need to be optimized.

I can't find any examples of converting Java objects into compatible Postgres text file formats, so any feedback helps.

How would you approach this problem?

**Additional Info:**

My table is pre-existing and can't be deleted since it's the back-end for my webapp and multiple users are connected at any given time.

I understand temporarily removing indexes prior to using `COPY` can increase performance, but I'm only requiring max 50,000 rows to be inserted or copied at a time, not millions.

StackExchange told me to ask here.

Comment: the question is from where do the objects come from?

Comment: okay can you process the user's data and persist it in the database in a single request? this would eleminate the need of the mainMap and processing big batches

Comment: Once a user uploads a spreadsheet, I have to iterate row-by-row. So, after I iterate the first row for example, what do I do with that cleansed data prior to processing the next row? I don't see how I can "persist" that single row's data in a database without sending an expensive INSERT query. That's why I'm storing it in RAM, so after all iterations are complete, I bulk INSERT/COPY with minimal queries. What am I not understanding?

Comment: if I understood you correctly the mainMap represents a single spreadsheet from a single user and counts 50k rows with 50 columns per row?

Comment: No, the user uploads a spreadsheet with max 50,000 rows of data, but only 35 columns.  I then need to iterate row-by-row to cleanse each cell of that data in different ways. Based on that row's data, I then add my own additional 15 <key,value> pairs to the inner `Map`. Hence the target table having 50 columns. `mainMap` by the time it's fully composed is essentially an identical data replication of what the target table should have.

Comment: how about creating a csv file and importing it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2987433/1879409

Comment: Do you think a CSV import would be more efficient than Ancoron's answer below?

Comment: @Mathomatic Whether or not a CSV import would be more efficient largely depends on how long it takes to convert that data to CSV in the first place (or if you can get it in a `COPY`-friendly format in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Java is certainly not the best option to do this kind of ETL, it certainly is possible and with rather little overhead using standard `INSERT` statements and prepared queries:

```java
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO my_table (col_a, col_b, ...)"
        + " VALUES (?, ?, ...)");
int batchSize = 1000;
int rows = 0;
for (Map<String, String> values : mainMap.values()) {
    int i = 0;
    stmt.setString(++i, values.get("col_a"));
    stmt.setString(++i, values.get("col_b"));
    // ...
    stmt.addBatch(); // add the row to the batch
    if (++rows % batchSize == 0) {
        // batch-sizing: execute...
        stmt.executeBatch();
    }
}

if (rows % batchSize != 0) {
    // a last execution if necessary...
    stmt.executeBatch();
}
conn.commit(); // atomic action - if any record fails, the whole import will fail
```

Alternatively, you could write out the Map into a file and use the [`CopyManager`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html), but I seriously doubt this would be any faster than with the batched inserts (would be different for millions of rows, though).

Comment: This looks promising. I'll report back. Thanks

Comment: I feel compelled to accept your answer as it was first, correct, cohesive and also provided interesting info about `conn.commit()` I didn't know. Thanks for the support. +1

Answer (score 2):

[`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) may indeed be the recommended way for initial bulk uploads, but there are limitations considering your initial data is stored in memory in a Java `Map`:

- Firstly, it expects to load from a file (local to the server, and readable by its user), or a program (again, executed locally on the server), or via `STDIN`. None of these options are particularly friendly to a JDBC connection.
- Secondly, even if you could prepare the data in that format (assuming you're on the same machine to prepare such a file, for example), you'd still need to convert the data held in memory in Java into the format `COPY` expects. That processing probably wouldn't make it worth using `COPY`.

I would instead create a `PreparedStatement` to insert your 50 columns, and then iterate through to execute that prepared statement for each `Map` in `mainMap.values()` (i.e. 50 columns each time).

You can gain speed using [`executeBatch()`](https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing). That said, I wouldn't execute all the 50000 in one batch, but in sub-batches.

I'd do something like this:

```
    int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

    List<String> keyNames = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO xyz (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)")) {
        for (Map<String, String> rowMap : mainMap.values()) {
            int j = 1;
            // You need the keynames to be in the same order as the columns
            // they match.
            for (String key : keyNames) {
                ps.setString(j, rowMap.get(key));
                j++;
            }
            ps.addBatch();

            if (i > 0 && i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (i % BATCH_SIZE != 1) {
            // More batches to execute since the last time it was done.
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I'm spending some time now to really understand your guys answers before replying further.

Comment: I had to accept the other as it was first and also correct, but yours is very similar so thank you. You validated my concern about using `COPY` here and taught me some interesting tidbits. +1