# Passing SQL Variable Using IN Expression in Python SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, parameter-passing

Best practice for passing a SQL query in Python is to use (?) placeholders. I'm running into an issue where I have an IN expression for my SQL query and cannot determine how to pass the variable arguments to the placeholder. *Edit: This differs from other answers (as pointed out in comments) in that other answers don't include unpacking.* My working code is:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "Select touchtonekey, COUNT(touchtonekey) as touchedthismanytimes from vw_callhandlertraffic\
            where callhandlername = ? and createddatetime between ?\
            and ? and touchtonekey IN ('1','2') Group By touchtonekey Order by touchtonekey"

data = cursor.execute(query,'My CallHandler','2019-10-09 13:00:00',
                      '2019-12-09 13:59:59')
```

But when I try to remove the IN arguments with this code:

```
query = "Select touchtonekey, COUNT(touchtonekey) as touchedthismanytimes from vw_callhandlertraffic\
            where callhandlername = ? and createddatetime between ?\
            and ? and touchtonekey IN ? Group By touchtonekey Order by touchtonekey"

data = cursor.execute(query,'My CallHandler','2019-10-09 13:00:00',
                      '2019-12-09 13:59:59', "('1','2')")
```

I get:

```
Right hand side of IN expression must be a COLLECTION type.
```

And If I remove the quotes from the parenthesis, I get:

```
Invalid application buffer type. (-11116) (SQLBindParameter)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)

Comment: Specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233213/4799172) answer, where you need to create placeholders. Note that some SQL dialects have limits to how many parameters you can have in an IN clause

Comment: Oops, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/4799172) answer, even. They basically say the same thing. But actually, they're missing unpacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *almost* a dupe of [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/283645/4799172) but there's a couple of things missing:

1. You have other parameters, not just for your `IN` clause, so you'll need some unpacking
2. A note about the fact that some SQL dialects (e.g. SQLite) will have limits on the [number of parameters you can pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6582902/4799172).

Corrected code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

membership_data = [1, 2] 
placeholders = ', '.join(['?' for item in membership_data])

query = """
        SELECT touchtonekey, COUNT(touchtonekey) AS touchedthismanytimes 
        FROM vw_callhandlertraffic
        WHERE callhandlername = ? AND createddatetime BETWEEN ? AND ? 
            AND touchtonekey IN ({}) 
        GROUP BY touchtonekey 
        ORDER BY touchtonekey
        """.format(placeholders) # Add the placeholders to your IN clause

data = cursor.execute(query,
                      ('My CallHandler',
                      '2019-10-09 13:00:00',
                      '2019-12-09 13:59:59',
                      *membership_data)) # Unpack the list
```

Note the use of `*`, [the "splat"/"unpacking" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950690/python-unpacking-operator) to make a flat tuple of arguments to `execute`

Comment: This was a perfect solution. Thank you for the help @roganjosh.

Comment: @RandyStegnerSr. if you feel that this has answered your question, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (which applies to your previous question also)

Comment: What would I do without you @roganjosh? I appreciate you helping me on more than just the problem I had! It's users like you that make Stack Overflow so awesome.

Answer (score 0):

While I was typing up my question I figured it out. Since I didn't see an answer on Stack Overflow (I may have just not been able to find one) I figured I would post the question and then answer it in case it helps someone else. The key is to always use the = ? syntax and then include the IN keyword in the parameter like so:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = "Select touchtonekey, COUNT(touchtonekey) as 
             touchedthismanytimes from vw_callhandlertraffic\
             where callhandlername = ? and createddatetime between ?\
             and ? and touchtonekey = ? Group By touchtonekey Order by\ 
             touchtonekey"

    data = cursor.execute(query,'My CallHandler','2019-10-09 13:00:00',
                                 '2019-12-09 13:59:59',"IN ('1','2')")
```

Comment: Nope, this isn't figured out. This is hard-coded. Your initial idea was on the correct lines, you just didn't quite execute it correctly.

Comment: @roganjosh agreed, you should never have to include the keyword `IN` as part of your parameter substitution

Comment: @roganjosh, then what is the correct way to execute? I'm not a developer, I simply created a few scripts for some telecom reporting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I linked to it under your question, twice

Comment: I'm sorry about that as I totally missed it. I failed to refresh page. Duly noted for the future though. Thanks for helping a noob.