# java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow while using IN operator

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sqlexception

I implemented a Java application which queries a database based on given set of ids using the query:

```
select * from STUDENT where ID in (?)
```

The set of ids will be used to replace `?`. However, occasionally, I receive an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4319)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:187)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:712)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:434)
```

After some testing, I realized that if I divide the list of ids into many sub-lists with smaller size, the exception stops happening. For some reason, jdbc doesn't like putting too many values into `IN (?)`. I wonder if anyone has seen this issue before and has an explanation for it? As this issue never happens on production environment but only on a local one (which has less powerful resources), I suspect it has something to do with server's resources.

Thanks

Update: the source code that I'm using is:

```
// create a query
private String getQueryString(int numOfParams) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    out.append("select * from STUDENT where ID in (");
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfParams; i++) {
        if (i == numOfParams - 1) {
            out.append("?");
        } else {
            out.append("?, ");
        }
    }
    out.append(")");
}

// set parameters
private void setParams(PreparedStatement ps, Set<String> params) {
    int index = 1;
    for (String param: params) {
        ps.setString(index++, param);
    }
}

public void queryStudent(Connection conn, Set<String> ids) throws Exception {
    String query = this.getQueryString(ids.size());
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    this.setParams(ps, ids);
    ps.executeQuery();

    // do some operations with the result
}
```

Comment: This means that the numeric value that you're querying is larger than the DB field can hold. Moreover, you can only pass one value for each `? `.

Comment: @Noob UnChained - As you surely aware SQL `IN` clause is specifically intended for operation over the list of multiple values, either hard-coded or returned by sub-query.

Comment: I am talking of passing parameters from java to the prepared statement .

Comment: @Long Thai - Could you please add a relevant `JDBC` part of your Java code to your post? (I'm not saying that there's something wrong with it).

Comment: @Noob UnChained - OP stated that this problem **never** happens in production. That leads me to believe that his syntax must be OK. Also, even in his test environment, the problem seems to disappear once he **splits a long list into smaller ones**.

Comment: How is the 'set' passed? You can't pass a string of values for example, as those would be interpreted as a single value. In fact that sounds like that might be happening - you pass '123,456' expecting that to be treated as `in (123, 456)` but it's actually treated as `in(to_number('123,456'))`, i.e. `in(123456)`. Once you get more than a few items in the 'list' the `to_number` part would throw that error. But then, unless you only passed a single value, it wouldn't give you the expected results, so something else is missing from this picture, perhaps - since you said it never happens in prod.

Comment: The cleanest way I know to pass a variable list of values to an `in()` is with an array, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6956025/266304). It doesn't look like you're dong that though. Showing at least the `setXXX()` statement and sample data you're passing might clarify things. (And I realise my previous comment was pretty much echoing @NoobUnChained...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by conflict of ojdbc driver between GlassFish and application. In order to fix it, I need to:

- Update application's pom.xml (as I'm using maven) to use a latest
  ojdbc which is ojdbc6-11.2.0.3
- Add ojdbc6-11.2.0.3 to GlassFish lib
- If necessary, manually remove the ojdbc jar from deployed applications' lib in glassfish (apparently this is not cleared by undeploy)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check MySQL and/or JDBC [max packet size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) setting? That usually bites you with large IN (...) lists.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs with the ID property or some other integer property  type of your entity 
look your stacktrace>

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:187)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:712)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:434)
```

Any value returned from the query does not fit on this property!
Change the properties Integer and try to work with the next integer types (long, Long BigInteger) in all fields of Integer type in your entity.