# java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

Tags: java, jsf-2, oracle11g

I am building a pie chart and a bar graph on the same page using JSF, and  both conponents getting information from this query:

```
select 'ACCOUNTS'PRODUCT,sum(ACCT_BAL_LCY) AMOUNT from account_master where schm_type in(?, ?, ?,?) and ACCT_BAL_LCY >0 
union select 'BILLS'PRODUCT, sum(LIAB_AMT_LCY)AMOUNT from bills_details union select 'DOCUMENTARY CREDITS'PRODUCT,sum(LIAB_AMOUNT)AMOUNT 
from DC_DETAILS union select 'GUARANTEES'PRODUCT, sum(LIAB_AMT_LCY)AMOUNT from BG_DETAILS;
```

The method executing it is :

```
 private void createPieModel() {
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();
        ChartSeries act = new ChartSeries();
        act.setLabel("Product Types");
        Connection conn;
        db = new DBConnection();
        conn = db.getDbConnection();
        pr = new BiProperties();
        try {
            String sql = pr.getDBProperty().getProperty("liability.bank");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, "SBA");
            ps.setString(2, "CAA");
            ps.setString(3, "TDA");
            ps.setString(4, "CCA");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                pieModel.set(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2));
                act.set(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2));//Error on this Line
                cities.put(i, rs.getString(1));
                i++;

            }
            categoryModel.addSeries(act);

        } catch (SQLException asd) {
            log.debug(Level.FATAL, asd);
        }
    }
```

At times both Graphs Shows at, times none of the graphs show and at other times, only the Pie chart Show. On checking the Back end I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
```

How can I avoid this as it is happening randomly??

Comment: This may be helpful:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569578/java-sql-sqlexception-numeric-overflow-while-using-in-operator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569578/java-sql-sqlexception-numeric-overflow-while-using-in-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it is thrown by aggregate functions in your SQL.
AFAIR by default SQL will define a variable to hold an aggregate function result to be the same type as the parameter of this function. You may want to redefine it as greater precision/size variables in your SQL.

Comment: I havo no function except sum() in this sql, this is a plain select statement from the tables in  question.

Comment: It applies to any aggregate functions if your column is defined as too small to hold the aggregated value.