# Update with JDBC for multiple rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a very simple SQL "update table where ID in (1,2,3)"

When I am doing

```
String sql = "update table where ID in (?)";
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList();
ids.add(1);
ids.add(2);
ids.add(3);
jdbc.update(sql, new Object[] { ids });
```

I recieve wrong sql in output

```
update table where ID in ('1,2,3')
```

How can I rid of this extra quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't pass an `Array` as a `Parameter` in a `PreparedStatement`. A similar question can be found here:

[PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

And some alternatives can be found here:

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement needs to be of the form:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=?, column2=?,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

i.e. note that

- you have to specify the columns that you want to update
- for each value that you need to provide, you need a placeholder `?` symbol
- for each value, you need a corresponding `setInt(pos, value)` call

Check out the [PreparedStatement tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more info. Excerpt below:

```
String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateSales.setInt(1, 100);
....
```

Comment: His problem isn't the `SET`s statements, he just messed up the example he gave.