# SQLite query selecting number from list

Tags: python, sqlite

When you want to write a query in `Python` that will select (from `SQLite` database) all the books that have 300 pages, you will write:

```
numsPages = 300
cur.execute("select * from  books where number_of_pages = :numsPages", locals())
```

The problem is when you want to select books that have number of pages from certain set

```
lst = computeListFromVariousInputs() # lst is list containing natural numbers
cur.execute("select * from  books where number_of_pages in :lst", locals())
```

The above statement is not possible.

It's difficult to write many `or` operators in the statement, so I'd like to use rather the `in` operator.

How would you write the query without using many `or` operators and using some `Python` list or other data structure?

Maybe, the example seems not practical (and it is) but this question is more understandable when I use this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the statement youself, e.g.:

```
a = [100, 200, 300, 400]
## The a bit more formatting is used because the list contains integers, i.e., the join with string casting
stmt = 'select * from books where number_of_pages in ({0})'.format(', '.join([str(v) for v in a]))

print stmt
>>> select * from books where number_of_pages in (100, 200, 300, 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

A good breakdown of the problem you're running into, and your options for solutions can be found here:

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

This was taken from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/189399/1232478