# Eliminating quotes in prepared statement in mysql n java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a prepared statement like this

```
stmt = select * from table_name where id IN (?);
```

Once I pass the parameters the stmt looks like way

```
stmt = select * from table_name where id IN ('1,2,3');
```

There is no error while executing the query. However the `resultset` is returned only for the `id=1`. Is there some way I can eliminate the quotes / get the `resultset` for all these id's.

```
stmt = select * from table_name where id IN (?);

select GROUP_CONCAT(id) id from table ;

if(rs.next()){

    stmt.setString(1,rs.getString("id"));

    stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the id field?

Comment: Your ORM is treating the variable you are passing in as a string, not an array. You probably have to just pass an array to it instead. What ORM are you using? Show the full code you use to run the query.

Comment: the ids are the resultset of another query when i use stmt.setString(1,rs.getstring(id)); the quotes bind with it internally

Comment: @Archana, please edit your answer and post the full code you are using to generate that query.

Comment: the code looks something like i have written above.

Comment: For another explanation, along with a couple alternative solutions, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives and then here - http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what the ID type is, but I believe you should actually be preparing a statement with each possible value as a separate parameter:

```
select * from table_name where id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Then add the three values for the three parameters. It's a common problem with parameterized SQL - when you want to be able to specify a variable number of values, you need to vary the SQL. There *may* be a MySQL-specific way of coping with this (like [table-valued parameters in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)) but I don't believe there's a generic JDBC way of doing this.

Comment: Why would you do it that way? Most ORMs (all ORMs I've ever seen) allow you to essentially use a "(?)" as a splat if you pass an array for that parameter. No need to know the number of items ahead of time.

Comment: @BenLee: Most ORMs would, sure - but they'll be generating *SQL* with the right number of ?s. There's a big difference between what you give to an ORM and what it does to fire off a query. There's no indication that the OP is even using an ORM.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. That's true, but I believe the OP already knows that. It looks like he is just having problems with his ORM. I would say the fact that he has a "prepared statament" and talks about "passing parameters" are strong indications that he is using an ORM.

Comment: @BenLee: Um, I don't think so. `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and the various `set` methods which are used to set parameters. On the other hand, there's *nothing* in the description which indicates an ORM.

Comment: stmt = select * from table_name where id IN (?);

select GROUP_CONCAT(id) id from table ;

if(rs.next()){

stmt.setString(1,rs.getString("id"));

stmt.executeQuery();
}
the code is something like this. I dont have a prior knowledge of the number of ids fetched in the prev query

Comment: @Archana: Rather than getting the database to concatenate the IDs, you should fetch them yourself, then build the SQL with the appropriate number of parameters.

Comment: There can be more then a 100 ids.. If i concatenate in the code it will be time consuming.

Comment: @Archana: You're doing a *database query*. Do you really think a few simple string operations (using `StringBuilder` for efficiency) will be the bottleneck?

Comment: Even though i build the string. I wont know the number to parameters to be passed when creating the prepared stmt

Comment: @Archana: Yes you will - you just need to delay preparing the statement until you've got the parameters.

Comment: hmm Oh that way.. Will it be ok if i put the prepared statement within a loop? won't it compile every time it enters the loop?

Comment: @Archana: Yes, it will be prepared each time - although if you've got a smart connection pool it may only prepare it once for each number of parameters. However, it'll still be relatively quick. See also the link that Perception mentioned: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Comment: oh ok i got it.. But the thing is the ids can be upto 10000. Looping like this will be a bad idea i think.. There is really no other function to eliminate the quotes which it binds internally? Thank you soo much for the quick reply

Comment: @Archana: If you have 10,000 IDs to search through and you've already fetched this data from a database, there's probably a better approach using a join...