# Java PreparedStatement set IN parameter as int array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN ?
```

I wish to set the PreparedStatement's `IN` parameter as an `int[]`.  For example, an integer 
array of `{1, 2, 3, 4}` would become `IN (1,2,3,4)` in the query.

**Is there a simple way to achieve this functionality using PreparedStatement's methods, or must I dynamically create the `IN` parameter as a string by looping over the array?**

I imagine something similar to [`#setString(int parameterIndex, String x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) but of course for an int array.

Comment: I don't think it works like that.  I think you need to find a different syntax in which there are multiple ?'s and you set each one's value.  Pretty cool thought, though.

Comment: You are going to have to write your own method. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1916391/738746, which you can reuse. Notice that arguments is not an array of `int`s but an array of `Object`s.

Comment: I was about to suggest doing what you just mentioned: dynamically build a query by looping over the array.  If you want something more convenient, use JPA 2 (where you can assign Collections to query parameters).

Comment: Nice find @BheshGurung.  As my question is a duplicate of that, I'm voting to close it.  (I am not deleting it, though, because I feel like my question's title is more search-friendly for future programmers with this same question).

Comment: How about changing the title of the the other question and deleting this one then?

Comment: @reprogrammer I considered that, but the other question applies to a broader situation.  Several answers skip the usage of `IN` and take entirely different approaches to the issue.  While that answer applies to *all* `IN` alternatives, mine only applies to setting an `int[]` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of to accomplish this is to alter the query string before you create the prepared statement to add new ?s.  Then just perform the binds as normal.

Comment: I am marking this as accepted, because it is indeed the approach I have chosen to take, but I'm not upvoting it because it came after the question was answered via the comments.  Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Spring JDBC. See how easy to start working with it:

```
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate t = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("ids", Arrays.asList(1, 2));
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = t.queryForList("select * from t1 where id in (:ids)", params);
```

You will see that it's not only IN what's good about Spring JDBC. Named parameters, no need to create / close Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet, no checked exceptions, declarative transaction support and many other things.

Comment: +1, Very interesting approach. However this would require that I rewrite the majority of my application to accommodate (and I don't know whether this approach pools connections for async use), so I won't be taking this route.