# PreparedStatement with thousands parameters in a IN clause

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I did read the solution from this Question [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives). But in my case, I have about 5000 parameters in a In clause and it would lead to java.sql.SQLException: Prepared or callable statement has more than 2000 parameter markers.

I was using a SQL like

```
String sql = "select * from project in " + projectIds.toString()
```

`projectIds` is a StringBuilder which is like "(1,2,3,4....)" But code security report says that it might lead to a sql injection. So I have to use ? placeholder to avoid it.

I tried to use

```
String sql = "select * from project where charindex(','+convert(varchar(max),id)+',', ?)>0";
statement.setString(1,projectIds.toString);//projectIds like ",1,2,3,4,"..
```

But it ends up with an incorrect syntax error.

Is there any solution???

Comment: Your sql, *charindex* seems not correct.
Suggest you check it again, and rewrite it in another way if you can .

Answer (score 2):

Hogan's suggestion to use a table instead is a good one.  The only thing I'd change is the query, because `JOIN` produces a row for every value in tablelist.  Instead (guessing at your column names)

```
select * from project 
where projectID in (select id from tablelist)
```

or

```
where exists (select 1 from tablelist where id = projectID)
```

Comment: Please see the comment I replied to Hogan. Thx

Comment: If databases A and B are on the same server, you could join them if you can arrange for permissions.  You could also insert into a global temporary table.  Really, the DBAs should help you, not erect stupid obstacles.  Worst case, you can pass in a string, loop over it with charindex or something, insert the values in to a table variable, and join.

Comment: Join does not produce a row, it was an inner join... a left join would do so.  I did not use a left join.\

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to not use an in statement.  Instead you should put all the values you want to check for in a table and use a join.

For example if you had a table with one column (called id) that had the list then your statement would look like this:

```
 select *
 from project
 join tablelist on project.project = tablelist.id
```

This will be much faster because SQL servers are quite good at performing joins quickly.

---

You can also do this with a CTE.  For example:

```
WITH tablelist as
(
   SELECT 1 AS id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 5
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 6
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 7
   // More if needed
)
select *
from project
join tablelist on project.project = tablelist.id
```

This can be sent as one big query and would work.  Your only limit would be max size of a query, I've don't don't know if such a limit exists.

Comment: Actually, I don't have the update access to the database. We have 2 databases, A is a database for another App, which we don't have update access, and B is our own database. What I want to do is to retrieve the latest data from database A for those project IDs in database B. Any suggestion??

Comment: @WangWei - Yes, see above.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from project in " + projectIds.toString()`

is incorrect syntax, it should be something like

```
select * from project where id in (" + projectIds + ")";
```