# Enter a group of numbers into a prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I would like to enter a group of numbers into a `prepared statement` all at once. Here is what I am trying

```
String parameters = "2,6,9";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, parameters);
```

However this only give me back the first person (person 2). This is b/c I am sending a string within the `IN` parameters. When you print out `preparedStatement.toString()` to the console the result that's being sent to the db is

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN ('2,6,9')
```

So my problem is the surrounding ticks, and I need to somehow get them out. Any ideas?

Ps: I know I can split the string by commas and go down that path since I've already implemented it. However, I'd like to avoid this if possible. Looking for a better way.

Comment: Well seems you don't have much of a choice. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives

Comment: Great links, answered a lot of things for me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting all the values:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select id, name from users where id in (?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setInt(1);
stmt.setInt(2);
stmt.setInt(3);
```

Note: This is from example on [javaranch](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2) page given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives).