# JDBC with MySQL - SELECT ... IN

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Using PreparedStatement to build a query that looks like this...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

...without knowing the number of strings in the IN statement

Constructing a string like...

```
"'foo', 'bar'"
```

...and passing that in with ps.setString() results in:

```
"\'foo\', \'bar\'"
```

Which is probably a good thing, but it makes this approach to my problem useless.

Any ideas on how to pass in an unknown number of values into a JDBC PreparedStatement **without** dynamically creating the query string too (this query lives in a file for easy reuse and I'd like to keep it that way)?

Comment: You can use an `Array` object. `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN ?` with `PreparedStatement#setArray(1, anArrayObject);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that depends if JDBC driver supports `setArray`.

Comment: See [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/178479/2390083)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use a method that will modify the query to modify the query accordingly. This is a basic example that omits error handling for simplicity:

```
public String addDynamicParameters(String query, List<Object> parameters) {
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder(query);
    queryBuilder.append("?");
    for (int i = 1; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
        queryBuilder.append(", ?");
    }
    queryBuilder.append(") ");
    return queryBuilder.toString();
}

public void addParameters(PreparedStatement pstmt, List<Object> parameters) {
    int i = 1;
    for(Object param : parameters) {
        pstmt.setObject(i++, param);
    }
}

public void testDynamicParameters() {
    String query = "SELECT col3 FROM tableX WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 IN (";
    List<Object> parametersForIn = ...;
    query = addDynamicParameters(query, parametersForIn);
    List<Object> parameters = ...;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = ...; //using your Connection object...
    parameters.addAll(parametersForIn);
    addParameters(pstmt, parameters);
    //execute prepared statement...
    //clean resources...
}
```