# Inserting ArrayList of Objects in Oracle Procedure Callable Statement as Argument using OJDBC Connection

Tags: java, oracle, arraylist

I have successfully implemented connection with oracle using `ojdbc6.jar`.

Now I have curiosity that how can I insert `Arraylist` containing objects of specific class into oracle database by procedural call?

For example I have `MyEmployee` class and I have made `Arraylist` of  Employee Class as follows :

```
List<MyEmployee> array = new ArrayList<MyEmployee>();
array.add(requestDetails1);
array.add(requestDetails2);
```

I want that I pass this whole array in a manner while calling `Callable` Statement so that each object goes as a row in table.

Comment: Do you mean each `MyEmployee` Object should go to some table `Employee` as a row?Also, to get more accurate answers, show your JDBC code , INSERT or UPDATE SQL, and Table details too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add array parameters to your query using, preparedStatement.setArray() method.
Keep this one in mind: [java.sql.PreparedStatement.setArray() : Unsupported cross conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930386/java-sql-preparedstatement-setarray-unsupported-cross-conversion)