# What is the difference between inSet and inSetBind in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

The [ScalaDoc of the functions](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.ColumnExtensionMethods) has not been filled out.

I know that the methods are used for mimicking SQL's `IN` keyword (eg, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN VALUES(1, 42, 101)` could be done with `table.filter(_.id inSet Seq(1, 42, 101))`). I don't know what this "bind" version is or how to choose which I should be using.

Comment: @BobDalgleish The Slick source code is pretty hostile to human life.

Comment: [case in point](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/559c3ada405865e45a78a7b6a5429ce19275fa35/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala#L49)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`inSet` is an unsafe version of `inSetBind` which generates a safe/escaped sql value based on passed in input. In your example where the value is manually set, the two types of bind are equally safe.

Normally with bound parameters you get a performance boost (via generated prepared statement), but not the case with collection values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives) for the details.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference. Can you pls explain. I tried with the queries in slick. Found out that if I use inSet(List(1,2,3)) the query s built as where id in (1,2,3). If I use inSetBind(List(1,2,3)), the query becomes id in (?,?,?).

Comment: @YaduKrishnan the latter is the placeholder syntax referred to above, each ? is replaced with safe/escaped value.

Comment: what do u mean by "safe/escaped" values? can you pls give an example?

Comment: @YaduKrishnan lookup sql injection attack, jdbc prepared statements, etc. Bottom line just use Slick's bind methods to ensure you have safe, performant queries -- simple ;-)