# Slick 3 join queries

Tags: scala, slick

I should select data from 3 tables 
result from each query I will use with **inSet** operation

```
 val q1 = tQ.filter(...).groupBy(_.s).map(_._1)
 val r1 = Await.result(db.run(q1.result), Duration.Inf)

 val q2 = tQ.filter(...inSet(r1)).groupBy(_.s).map(_._1)
 val r2 = Await.result(db.run(q2.result), Duration.Inf)

 val q3 = tQ.filter(...inSet(r2)).groupBy(_.s).map(_._1)
 val r3 = Await.result(db.run(q3.result), Duration.Inf)
```

Can I join 2 small queries to the ONE ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Slick queries are highly composable. Something like this should do:

```
val q = for {
  r1 <- tQ.filter(...).groupBy(_.s).map(_._1).result
  r2 <- tQ.filter(...inSet(r1)).groupBy(_.s).map(_._1).result
  r3 <- tQ.filter(...inSet(r2)).groupBy(_.s).map(_._1).result
} yield r3

Await.result(db.run(q), Duration.Inf)
```

If `X` is some type you want to pass to `inSet`, then your `.filter(...).groupBy(...).map(_._1)` type is `Query[Xs, X, Seq]`. Calling `.result` gives `DBIO[Seq[Xs]]`. Since you are in `for` comprehension block and all comprehensions have `DBIO` type, your `rN` results actually are `Seq[X]` so you can pass them to `inSet` method.

Check out documentation on [monadic joins](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#monadic-joins).

You might also want to consider using [inSetBind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579361/what-is-the-difference-between-inset-and-insetbind-in-slick).