# How to use IN clause in Slick?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, scala, slick

I have a query which is written is using slick, it is not a plain slick query.
The query is a select query which fetches the records from a table called  Employee. The results are of type `Employee` class.

Now there is a list of Strings

```
val nameFilter= List("Sachin","Naveen"")
```

and this "nameFilter" comes dynamically and it may have any number of names

```
var result= dbHandle.db.run((query.drop(10).take(10)).result
```

The variable `query`  is just a select query for the Employee table which selects a range of records from  11 to 20.

Now I need to filter the records which have names mentioned in the 'nameFilter' and then select the records from  11 to 20. That means I need a query with 'IN' clause.

Please note that this is not a plain Slick SQL query, I have to frame a query in the above format.

Comment: Do you want to make a change to the query ? Or just filter the matching?

Answer (score 19):

You can do this with the method .inSet (see [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html#id21)):

> Slick
>
> Slick queries are composable. Subqueries can be simply composed, where the types work out, just like any other Scala code.
>
> ```
> val address_ids = addresses.filter(_.city === "New York City").map(_.id)
> people.filter(_.id in address_ids).result // <- run as one query
> ```
>
> The method .in expects a sub query. For an in-memory Scala collection, the method **.inSet** can be used instead.

So that would mean for your code:

```
val nameFilter= List("Sachin","Naveen")
val filteredQuery = query.filter(_.name.inSet(nameFilter))
var result= dbHandle.db.run((filteredQuery.drop(10).take(10)).result
```

Depending on the source of that input you should consider using **.inSetBind** to escape the input (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579361/what-is-the-difference-between-inset-and-insetbind-in-slick)).