# Optimizing PostgreSQL ANY statements using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

PostgreSQL supports the "ANY" SQL operator which is a really nice alternative to "IN" statements for us Java programmers that rely on JDBC/PreparedStatements. For example, instead of creating a long SQL string with thousands of IDs, we can do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240302/777443):

```
final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
     "SELECT my_column FROM my_table where search_column = ANY (?)"
);
final Long[] values = getValues();
statement.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("bigint", values));
final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

I recently stumbled across an [interesting article](https://www.datadoghq.com/2013/08/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/) which claims to have a 100x improvement in executing "ANY" clauses by changing this:

```
"WHERE search_column = ANY (ARRAY[15368196, -- 11,000 other keys --)])"
```

To this:

```
"WHERE search_column = ANY (VALUES (15368196), -- 11,000 other keys --)"
```

**Questions**:

1. Which syntax does the PostgreSQL JDBC driver use? I suspect the createArrayOf() method is creating an ARRAY[] vs VALUES() but I don't know how to verify this.
2. If, in fact, the createArrayOf() method is creating an ARRAY[], what is the best approach for using the VALUES() instead?

I would prefer not to have to do something like this:

```
final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
 "SELECT my_column FROM my_table where search_column = ANY (VALUES (?), (?), (?), ...)"
);
```

A little more context/background for why I'm using "ANY" clauses can be found here:
[PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? For a plain SELECT and also for the execution of the prepared statement. It's all about the (best) query plan!

Comment: I don't think you can.