# IN clause in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using ojdbc6 jar and I want to use the In clause in a PreparedStatement.

I have used the `createArrayOf(String,ArrayOfString)` method of the connection object.

I got an error as Unsupported Feature

I have checked the PhysicalConnection class in the implementation for this method is

```
public Array createArrayOf(String s, Object aobj[]) throws SQLException {
        SQLException sqlexception = DatabaseError.createUnsupportedFeatureSqlException();
        sqlexception.fillInStackTrace();
        throw sqlexception;
    }
```

I have checked the ojdbc14.jar for this method. In that .jar file this method is not defined.

Please help me, which jar do I have to use? I want to implement the In clause functionality in the PreparedStatement.

Comment: Please post your error message. Also, what Oracle version are you connecting to? What is the SQL string you are using in the PreparedStatement? Please include more information

Comment: Also, why don't you just say "AND some_value IN ('value1', 'value2')" right in the SQL for the PreparedStatement?

Comment: I am using oracle "11.2.0.4.0 " and Ojdbc 6

Comment: Once you post the other information into your question, we can help you more :-)

Comment: see my query somthing like this...
Select * from Employee where ID IN(?). 
I have tried to set this holder with Array Of the oracle... like
Array ids=connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR",new String[]{"0","1"});
prestmt.setArray(1,ids);

Comment: `IN` clause _does not_ support `bind array`.. instead you have to construct the query like `IN (:val1,:val2...:valn)`

Comment: And I am getting this error java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createArrayOf(PhysicalConnection.java:9309)

Comment: ok but i dont know how many numbers of values will be there.. I canonot make it dynamic

Comment: So you get an String array of the values and it can be different sizes?

Comment: Yes I am getting List from and I am creating Array of it and one more i cant touch the Query part as well because placeholder defined is constants accourding to requirnment

Comment: How can it be a constant if the number of values can change?

Comment: you can make it dynamic.. simply with generating variable names.. unfortunately, Oracle *DONOT* support binding array to IN clause with SQL. There's a `PL/SQL` Solution for this, which might be cumbersome.

Comment: I have read the answer from the stack overflow only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254133/jdbc-prepared-statement-how-to-set-a-list   -->  It seems the best answer in JDBC 4 is to use setArray().

PreparedStatement pstmnt = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatment( "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id NOT IN ( ? )" );
pstmt.setArray(  1,  dataSource.getConection().createArrayOf( "string", excludeList.toArray() )  );

Comment: Did you look at this protected post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternativesc

Comment: Few Other Database support this. Oracle, don't. Hence this runtime exception.

Comment: ohh ok... yes I have check that protected post as well... I thought by upgrading driver or other method solution will be there but no luck.. ok

Comment: Thank you friends for your valuable time,.. please let me know if there any other solution .. I have to execute the preparedstatment number of time as number of IDS are there,, this is only back up solution....

Comment: The only approach that worked for me. Unfortunately not as clean as createArrayOf - http://blogs.itemis.de/kloss/2009/03/05/arrays-preparedstatements-jdbc-and-oracle/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do something like...

```
SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE ID IN ?
```

I had a similar problem in the past and tried all sorts of tricks with JDBC and Oracle (such as user defined types etc), but this is what we ended up with...

1. Create a [global temporary table](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_global_temporary_tables.htm) containing a single ID column (scoped to the session - ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS)
2. Start a transaction
3. Insert all of the Ids you want using a batch statement into the temp table
4. Join to this table to get the results, for example...

   `SELECT * FROM TAB T INNER JOIN MyTempTable X ON T.ID = X.ID`
5. When you commit, the temp table is truncated

If you need to do several of these in the same transaction, be sure to delete form the temp table first.

(Also, we had loads of problems with driver versions and things like setArray etc, so we settled on this)

Comment: @user2343420 that's a pain!! If you have to resort to "dynamic" sql, beware that some DBMS (such as Oracle) only support a maximum of 1,000 items in an IN clause. You could always prepare 1,000 statements and if you have more than 1,000 things, do them in multiple batches...