# SQL query using Integer ArrayList and PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

I have this sql statement.

```
String sqlQuery ="SELECT "
                +"A.SCOPE_ID, A.SCOPE_KEY, A.NAME, A.DESCRIPTION, A.ROLES "
                +"FROM IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE AS A "
                +"INNER JOIN AM_API_SCOPES AS B "
                +"ON A.SCOPE_ID = B.SCOPE_ID WHERE B.API_ID IN (?)";
```

and I have this Integer ArrayList

```
List<Integer> apiIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Suppose the array list have some values in it. How can I get the result set for all the apiIds in one database call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/189399/1743880

Comment: well you can just concatenate your int values with `,` and pass that string as input in your query

Comment: String newSql = sqlQuery.replace( "?", apiIds.toString( ).replace( "[",""  ).replace("]","") );