# One parameter with multiple arguments - Selection and SelectionArgs

Tags: java, sqlite, cursor

I have encountered this problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range. The statement has 1 parameters.
```

As a result of:

```
String where = "id_1 = 50 AND id_2 = ?";
//The String[] is ideally of dynamic length and not necessarily 3 in size.
String[] whereArgs = {"60", "61", "62"};

cursor.setSelection(where);
cursor.setSelectionArgs(whereArgs);
```

I am simply using it the wrong way. I have realized this already. But I would think it makes it evident what I am trying to accomplish.

My question: 
Is there a way for me to insert an array of varying length and arguments into a single parameter? Any best practices that I have missed. Have I simply baked myself into a bad situation?

The SQL statement I could be looking for:

```
WHERE id_1 = 50 AND ((id_2 = 60) OR (id_2 = 61) OR (id_2 = 62))
```

The only way I can think of to fix my problem is to create a string and build upon it in a loop the length of String[] adding OR (id_2 = xx) with every iteration. It just doesn't sound like a very good solution to me.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What about MySQL `IN()`? `"... AND id_2 IN ( ? )"` and build `whereArgs` so it's a string of comma separated values.

Comment: @marekful I have not tried that, no. I will give that one a shot.

Comment: That seems to be a flexible enough way in this case as you can easily join the array elements into a CSV list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives

Comment: @marekful That worked like a charm. Thanks! If you write an answer of it I can mark it.

Comment: @ykaganovich do I delete my thread?

Comment: @Dennis no need. Stackoverflow will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, constructing the WHERE clause dynamically is the correct solution. Use `StringBuilder.append()` rather than `+` to save some string construction overhead.

In some cases, you may also want just issue multiple statements. So instead of

```
select from table where id_1 = 50 AND (id_2 = ? OR id_2 = ? OR id_2 = ?);
```

You could do a [Batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) of

```
select from table where id_1 = 50 AND (id_2 = ?);
select from table where id_1 = 50 AND (id_2 = ?);
select from table where id_1 = 50 AND (id_2 = ?);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
String where = "id_1 = 50 AND (id_2 = ? OR id_2 = ? OR id_2 = ?)";

String[] whereArgs = {"60", "61", "62"};
```

Comment: Hi. I don't think that takes into consideration that my String[] can be of varying length.