# Error "ResultSet closed"

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist, resultset

Why do I get this error :

> Error :java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed

from this code:

```
try{   
        ArrayList<String> longArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        longArray.add("12345678912"); // All column in sqlite database are "text" so that's why I create String List 
        longArray.add("12345678911"); 
        System.out.println(longArray);
        String parameters = StringUtils.join(longArray.iterator(),",");  
        connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();  
        PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement("select columnA from TableUser where id in (?)");    
        pst.setString(1, parameters ); 
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(); 

        System.out.println(rs.getString("columnA")); // did not print anything, probably rs is empty
        rs.close();
```

Database details:
I have a table `TableUser` in database where there is a column "id" as Text.

Another question : Is value in database `12345678912` (TEXT) the same as `longArray.add("12345678912")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `if(rs.next())` or `while(rs.next())` after you retrieve the `ResultSet`.

For your other question...yes, they're both `Strings` aren't they?

Edit:
The problem was essentially trying to put multiple parameters into the `IN` statement in a `PreparedStatement`. See [PreparedStatement IN Clause Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Comment: That is right. But 
while(rs.next())
  {
   System.out.println(rs.getString("columnA"));
  }
did not print anything.. How can I fix it? Thank you so much

Comment: By making a query that doesn't return an empty resultset.

Comment: Try using a `Statement` and concatenating the ids to the query to see if it works (with the `'` delimiters for the ids if they're `TEXT`). It may be that the SQLite driver doesn't like the way you're using that prepared statement.

Comment: Could you help me to write it right? you mean it?

//String question = "(?)";
PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement("select`"+columnA+"` from '"+TableUser +" where ' = '"+id+"' = '"+question+"'");

Comment: See the link for discussion about how to work with the `IN` clause and `PreparedStatement` (it's still a lot better than using a raw `Statement`).