# PHP - How to substitute array as host parameter in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am able to bind values of type `int`, `str`, `bool` and `null` but I am unable to bind array type. 
I have tried both functions, i.e. `bindValue` and `bindParam` but neither of them worked.
How can I accomplish this ?

```
// a helper function to map Sqlite data type
function getArgType($arg) {
    switch (gettype($arg)) {
        case 'double':  return SQLITE3_FLOAT;
        case 'integer': return SQLITE3_INTEGER;
        case 'boolean': return SQLITE3_INTEGER;
        case 'NULL':    return SQLITE3_NULL;
        case 'string':  return SQLITE3_TEXT;
        default:
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument is of invalid type '.gettype($arg));
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (?)";
$params = [[10, 9, 6]]; // array of array
$dbpath = '/path/to/sqlite.sqlite';
$db = new SQLite3($dbPath, SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

try {
    foreach ($params as $index => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            /************* I am stuck here  *************/
            $ok = $stmt->bindParam($index + 1, $val);
            // Using bindValue also didn't worked!
        } else {
            $ok = $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, $val, getArgType($val));
        }

        if (!$ok) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to bind param: $val");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // NO exception is thrown from bindValue() or bindParam()
    $reason = "Error in binding statement. " . $ex->getMessage();
    die($reason);
}

$result = $stmt->execute();
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetchArray($mode)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
var_dump($data);
```

**Edit:** I already tried replacing single `?` with required number of question marks in param array, but then it is working only if my array has less than **1000** values! I think it's a limitation of how statements are prepared in SQLite3 in PHP.

Comment: Not familiar with SQLLite, but I believe you'll need to put a placeholder in place of each value in your query (e.g. 3 `?`s in your current example). Then bind each value from the array; or pass the array in the `execute`.

Comment: @chris85: it will only work if array has less than 1000 elements. I want a solution to work in all cases. thanks.

Comment: Is the limit you are hitting `PHP` or `sqllite`? Are you trying to take +1000 `POST` values?

Comment: Its sqlite limit. https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html see 9th point

Comment: I'm curious as to find out why you need to filter by more than 1000 values...

Comment: As I remember you need to bind a variable and it seems it will be accessed by reference, if you change it, next SQL-query will be changed too. Why you don't use `implode` instead of loop? Something like that: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$params).")";`. Is your `id`-field can be any type at the same time ? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) is similar question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **not possible**! You cannot bind an array.

The easiest solution for you problem would be the following:

1. Create the SQL-Query with one placeholder (`?`) per value in the array
2. Bind each value by iterating over the array.

But there are also another options (e.g. a sub-SELECT)

[More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189399/3975480) (even if it's a Java question, it is nearly the same topic/problem because the database type doesn't matter in this case)

*EDIT:* Normally, the SQL Limit for bound parameters is set so `999`, but you [can change it if you need to](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Comment: This solution has a limit of 999. I cannot bind more than 999 values. Any hint on how to change this default limit in php sqlite ?

Comment: @AtulVaibhav Sure you can change the SQLite limits. More information [on the official SQLite page](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). If this doesn't suit you, you can try other solutions from the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind arrays as a list for an `IN (?)` clause. Each value in the `IN` list must get its distinct place holder.

To make this dynamic, first determine the array of values and then dynamically build the SQL.

This would be your code:

```
$arrayParam = [10, 9, 6];
$placeHolders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($arrayParam), '?'));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN ($placeHolders) AND name = ?";
// Merge the "array" parameter values with any other parameter values
// into one non-nested array:
$params = array_merge($arrayParam, ['myname']);
// ...
    foreach ($params as $index => $val) {
        // No sub arrays allowed:
        $ok = $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, $val, getArgType($val));
        // ... etc
```

Answer (score 2):

(Caveat: This answer was written before the 'mysql' tag has been removed; I don't know if it `addslashes` works for sqlite3.)

In PHP, given $list as an array of values destined for an IN list:

```
$list = array(1, 2, 'abcd', 'double quote: "', "apostrophe: don't");
$ins = implode(', ', array_map(
        function($a) {
               return "'" . addslashes($a) . "'";
                     }, $list));
echo $sql = "... IN ($ins) ...";;
```

yields

```
... IN ('1', '2', 'abcd', 'double quote: \"', 'apostrophe: don\'t') ...
```

(Yes, this could be done with a normal `for` loop, without using `array_map` and an "anonymous function".)

Don't worry; quotes around numbers (`'123'`) is OK for numeric columns.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose a work-around in what you try to do. Pass the query result to a temporary table.

```
// a helper function to map Sqlite data type
function getArgType($arg) {
        switch (gettype($arg)) {
            case 'double':  return SQLITE3_FLOAT;
            case 'integer': return SQLITE3_INTEGER;
            case 'boolean': return SQLITE3_INTEGER;
            case 'NULL':    return SQLITE3_NULL;
            case 'string':  return SQLITE3_TEXT;
            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Argument is of invalid type '.gettype($arg));
        }
}
function getTempValues() {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTemp`";
$params = [$in]; // array of array
$dbpath = '/path/to/sqlite.sqlite';
$db = new SQLite3($dbPath, SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
    $data = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray($mode)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
function addToTemp($in) {
$sql = "SELECT * INTO `myTemp` FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` = ?";
$params = [$in]; // array of array
$dbpath = '/path/to/sqlite.sqlite';
$db = new SQLite3($dbPath, SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if(is_array($in)) {
foreach($in as $newValue) {
addToTemp($newValue);
}
} else {
 try {
        foreach ($params as $index => $val) {
                $ok = $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, $val, getArgType($val)); 
            if (!$ok) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to bind param: $val");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NO exception is thrown from bindValue() or bindParam()
        $reason = "Error in binding statement. " . $ex->getMessage();
        die($reason);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
}
 return getTempValues();
}

print_r(addToTemp([10,9,6]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add ?  placeholder as many as number of items in your array

```
Select * from table_a where field in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,.....)
```

If they are bigger than 1000 then split them into two or more queries.