# Can a prepared statement use multiple values

Tags: r, jdbc, prepared-statement

Consider an SQL statement like

```
Select * from items where id in (123,456,789)
```

Can I use a prepared statement like

```
Select * from items where id in ?
```

and then supply the parameter as a set or list? Maybe I'd need parentheses around the "?".

I'm planning to use this in R, but I guess it's a general query for JDBC.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives).  You may certainly create a prepared statement with a `WHERE IN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Two partial work-arounds:

1. Create a function that changes `in (?)` to `in (?,?,?)`, depending on the length of the supplied list of values, then break that array into individual values for binding.

   - Pros: one query; binding is straight-forward
   - Cons: not feasible with large lists; have to wrap your queries in query-manglers, not fool-proof
2. Upload values to a temp table and change your query to

   ```
   select * from items where id in (select val from temptable)
   ```

   - Pros: deal with arbitrary number of values; no need to trick SQL; binding is just as one would do for a multi-row insert
   - Cons: multiple calls; requires temp table and clean-up; might be problematic integrating with more complex queries (??)