# Does MySQL 'OR' and two SELECT statements have same complexity?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

`1. "SELECT id, name FROM Customers WHERE id = id1 OR id = id2"`

`2. "SELECT id, name FROM Customers WHERE id = id1"` and again, `"SELECT id, name FROM Customers WHERE id = id2"`

Does it take same time for the above two cases in the context of MySQL? OR How does OR gets implemented internally?

**EDIT:**

Assume `Customers`table is indexed on `id` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90% of a *simple* select is overhead (network, parsing, optimizing, etc).

`id = 123 OR id = 345` is optimized to `id IN (123, 345)`.  If there is an index on `id` (the `PRIMARY KEY` is an index), this is 2 probes into the table.

So if fetching one row is 100% of effort, then fetching 2 is about 110% of that (90% overhead, then 2 units of real work).

Meanwhile, 2 *separate* selects would be 200%.

On the other hand, if you have

```
WHERE x = 98 OR y = 65
```

there is no good indexing method for such.

Plan A:  A full table scan, checking x and y for every row.  Really slow for a big table.

Plan B:  Change it to

```
( SELECT ... WHERE x = 98 )
UNION
( SELECT ... WHERE y = 65 )
```

This will be more like 200%.  That is, making two queries *helps* in this case.

Plan C is "index merge union", which the Optimizer only occasionally resorts to.

Answer (score 1):

You should phrase this as:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM Customers
WHERE id IN (@id1, @id2);
```

Assuming that `id1` and `id2` are passed into the query, then they would only be similar if you had an index on `id` (which is reasonable).  Of course, running two queries incurs overhead of running two queries.  However, the *complexity* is the same, from the perspective of algorithmic analysis.

Without an index, the two-query version is slower by a factor of two, because it needs to scan the table twice.  However, although that is slower, it does not affect *complexity*.

Comment: @tezz (topicstarter) Yes it's also a known fact that the Oracle database optimizer (Not MySQL's optimizer i wished it did) rewrites `OR` conditions not 100% sure about the `IN()` and expands it to `SELECT .. WHERE id = <value> UNION ALL SELECT .. WHERE id = <value>` in most cases when the column is indexed because it's faster..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/189399/3881561 is a bit relevant to what you're saying. In 3rd highlighted-point, he/she points out that it's a bad idea to use `UNION ALL`. If so, how come Oracle's optimizer uses that?

Comment: We are going a bit to far offtopic now: *"In 3rd highlighted-point ..idea to use UNION ALL"*  Yes on unindexed columns it is on indexed column it's fine *"If so, how come Oracle's optimizer uses that? "* @tezz [Slow join behaviour with 'or' in predicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/slow-join-behaviour-with-or-in-predicate)  also notice the link [Optimizer Transformations: OR Expansion](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/or_expansion_transformation) very important`UNION [ALL]` can use parallel queries to fetch the results concurrently in Oracle database