# Rewrite Hibernate Criteria with IN clause so can reuse same PreparedStatement with different number of IN clauses

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I use the following Hibernate query alot when retrieving multiple records by their primary key

```
       Criteria c = session
                .createCriteria(Song.class)
                .setLockMode(LockMode.NONE)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids));
        List<Song> songs = c.list();
```

The problem is the number of ids can vary from 1 - 50, and every different number of ids requires a different PreparedStatement. That, combined with the fact that any particular prepared statement is tied to a particular database pool connection means that the opportunity to reuse a PreparedStatement is quite low.

Is there way I can rewrite this so that the same statement can be used with different number of in values, I think I read somewhere it could be done by using ANY instead but cannot find the reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli useful link but no mentin of hibernate in that question or answers so not duplicate

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using Hibernate or not. Prepared statements are SQL statements. And Hibernate generates these. So you have to look at the solution and write a Hibernate query that generates these SQL statements

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That is the question Im asking, how to create a Hibernate query, and that is not answerd in the linked question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the misunderstandig. Please read my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is called "in clause parameter padding" and can be activated with a hibernate property:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding"
    value="true"
</property>
```

Read more about this topic here: https://vladmihalcea.com/improve-statement-caching-efficiency-in-clause-parameter-padding/

Comment: thankyou that is a good answer, unfortunately I'm currenlty on Hibernate 4 so it not available but I do want to update to Hibernate 5. However is there also possible solution using ANY somehow do I can do in Hibernate 4.

Comment: You will have to provide a variety of statements 1-50 in clauses

Answer (score 0):

With some help I ended up getting a usual SQL connection from Hibernate, and then using standard SQL with ANY instead of IN. As far as I know using ANY means we only need a single prepared statement per connection so is better then using padded IN's. But because just using SQL not much use if you need to modify the data returned

```
 public static List<SongDiff> getReadOnlySongDiffs(List<Integer> ids)
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = HibernateUtil.getSqlSession();
            String SONGDIFFSELECT = "select * from SongDiff where recNo = ANY(?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SONGDIFFSELECT);

            ps.setObject(1,  ids.toArray(new Integer[ids.size()]));
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = new ArrayList<>(ids.size());
            while(rs.next())
            {
                SongDiff sd = new SongDiff();
                sd.setRecNo(rs.getInt("recNo"));
                sd.setDiff(rs.getBytes("diff"));
                songDiffs.add(sd);
            }
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            SessionUtil.close(connection);
        }
    }

 public static Connection getSqlSession() throws SQLException {
        if (factory == null || factory.isClosed()) {
            createFactory();
        }

        return ((C3P0ConnectionProvider)factory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().getService(C3P0ConnectionProvider.class)).getConnection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on an old version of Hibernate as suggested in the comments to [Simon's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773287/521799), as a workaround, you could use [jOOQ's `ParsingConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/) to transform your SQL by applying the [`IN` list padding feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-in-list-padding/) transparently behind the scenes. You can just wrap your `DataSource` like this:

```java
// Input DataSource ds1:
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(ds1, dialect);
ctx.settings().setInListPadding(true);

// Use this DataSource for your code, instead:
DataSource ds2 = ctx.parsingDataSource();
```

[I've written up a blog post to explain this more in detail here](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/04/22/use-in-list-padding-to-your-jdbc-application-to-avoid-cursor-cache-contention-problems/).

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)