# Use an property of an object which is array of strings in mapper XML

Tags: mybatis

I want to refer to a property in an object in my mapper file which is an array of strings in a SQL IN criteria.  The query does a count, so all it needs to return is a numeric value.  The query needs to adjust its count based on a flexible set of criteria defined in a filter object.  Some filters will be present (ie. not null), and others will be absent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="TotalUniqueUsers">
    <select id="getTotalUniqueUsers" 
            resultType="int" 
            parameterType="RequestFilter">
         SELECT *
         FROM MY_TABLE
         WHERE 
         <if test="quarterList!=null and quarterList.length>0">
             AND trim(FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME) IN #{quarterList javaType=list}
         </if>
    </select>
</mapper>


public class RequestFilter {
    private String[] quarterList;
    public String[] getQuarterList(){
        return this.quarterList;
    }
    public void setQuarterList(String[] quarterList){
        this.quarterList=quarterList;
    }
}
```

Note, there is no type handler for RequestFilter. I did not think I needed one. I'm not trying to take an object and condense it into say one field in some weird way. All I want to do is have an input parameter to the

With the above, I get 
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
...
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'quarterList javaType=list' in 'class RequestFilter'

I tried javaType=Array also, but get the same result. If I change the

```
#{quarterList javaType=list}
```

to

```
#{quarterList}
```

it says the typeHandler is null for the RequestFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no portable way to set the list or array to `IN` prepared statement parameter in JDBC and therefore in mybatis (there are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives/10240302#10240302) to do that if you are using postgres).

So in the general case you need to dynamically generate the query with a parameter per element in the list:

```
<select id="getTotalUniqueUsers" 
        resultType="int" 
        parameterType="RequestFilter">
     SELECT *
     FROM MY_TABLE
     WHERE 
     <if test="quarterList!=null and quarterList.length>0">
         trim(FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME) IN (             
            <foreach item='quarter' collection='quarterList' separator=','>
               #{quarter}
            </foreach>
         )
     </if>
</select>
```