# Can I use ANY or an ARRAY for an alternative to variable IN clause with Hibernate 4.3.11 and H2 1.4.199

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

Using Java 8, HIbernate 4.3.11 and H2 1.4.199

I create an html report made up of many pages and I have to make a larger number of queries simply with the where clause based on an IN call based on the primary key. If the number of values in the IN clause vary then a different prepared query needs to be prepared, existing ones cannot be reused. So I am trying to reduce the need for so many different prepared statements.

This is a solution in Hibernate 5 called *hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding* as described at 
 https://vladmihalcea.com/improve-statement-caching-efficiency-in-clause-parameter-padding/

However I cannot move to Hibernate 5, and it seems this solution has  been superceded by use of ANY clause or ARRAYS anyway. But I have not yet been able to get this working

*getSongDiffs1()* is my initial Hibernate based Criteria query, *getSongDiffs2()* is query rewritten to use native sql works but has no performance advantage, I then tried using ANY for *getSongDiffs2()* and ARRAYS with *getSongDiffs()* but these gave errors when preparing statements

Although I am trying to use native SQL because generated from Hibernate session  I am working with **org.hibernate.SQLQuery** rather than **Connection** so couldnt fully follow solution labelled Postgres solution at given [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

```
  public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs1(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            Criteria c = session
                    .createCriteria(SongDiff.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids));
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = c.list();
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs2(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from SongDiff where recNo in :recNos");
            q.addEntity(SongDiff.class);
            q.setParameterList("recNos", ids);
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = q.list();
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs3(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from SongDiff where recNo = ANY(:recNos)");
            q.addEntity(SongDiff.class);
            q.setParameterList("recNos", ids);
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = q.list();
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from SongDiff where recNo in :recNos)");
            q.addEntity(SongDiff.class);
            q.setParameter("recNos", ids.toArray());
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = q.list();
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Gives error

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM SONGDIFF WHERE RECNO IN ?[*]) "; expected "("; SQL statement:

Based on answer and trial and error below I wrote this

```
 public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(Integer next:ids)
            {
                sb.append(next +",");
            }
            sb.setLength(sb.length() -1);

            SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from SongDiff where recNo IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST("+sb.toString()+"))");
            q.addEntity(SongDiff.class);
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = q.list();
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

this runs without error, but I because not using parameterized the Hibernate debugging shows no ?s , i.e I get

```
08/10/2019 16.49.40:BST:DEBUG: select * from SongDiff where recNo IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35))
08/10/2019 16.49.40:BST:DEBUG: select * from SongDiff where recNo IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(32,33,34,35,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31))
```

So I assume this means they are seperate prepared statements which negates the point of this, so is it possible to get this working with **setParamter()**

Using the latest advise both ANY and UNNEST variations appear to send valid SQL

```
public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Integer next:ids)
        {
            sb.append(next +",");
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() -1);

        SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from SongDiff where recNo = ANY(:recNos)");
        q.addEntity(SongDiff.class);
        q.setParameter("recNos", ids.toArray(new Integer[10]));
        List<SongDiff> songDiffs = q.list();
        return songDiffs;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

but now there is a problem extracting the ResultSet

```
09/10/2019 08.02.14:BST:SongChangesCache:getSongDiffs:SEVERE: Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:could not extract ResultSet
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.listCustomQuery(StatelessSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at com.jthink.songkong.db.SongChangesCache.getSongDiffs(SongChangesCache.java:407)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.utils.HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.createAlbumFilesHtmlPage(HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.java:350)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.utils.HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.createAlbumsHtmlPage(HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.java:282)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.utils.HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.createArtistsHtmlPage(HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.java:198)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.utils.HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.<init>(HtmlAlbumArtistAlbumGridCreator.java:75)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.AbstractByMetadataSection.outputSection(AbstractByMetadataSection.java:306)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.fixsongsreport.ByArtistAlbumSection.call(ByArtistAlbumSection.java:34)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.fixsongsreport.ByArtistAlbumSection.call(ByArtistAlbumSection.java:19)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "X'aced0005757200145b4c6a6176612e6c616e672e496e74656765723bfe97ada00183e21b02000078700000000d737200116a6176612e6c616e672e496e746567657212e2a0a4f781873802000149000576616c7565787200106a6176612e6c616e672e4e756d62657286ac951d0b94e08b0200007870000000177371007e0002000000187371007e0002000000197371007e00020000001a7371007e00020000001b7371007e00020000001c7371007e00020000001d7371007e00020000001e7371007e00020000001f7371007e0002000000207371007e0002000000217371007e0002000000227371007e000200000023' (SONGDIFF: ""RECNO"" INTEGER NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
select * from SongDiff where recNo = ANY(?) [22018-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:455)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.table.Column.convert(Column.java:204)
    at org.h2.table.Column.convert(Column.java:185)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCondition.getCurrentValueList(IndexCondition.java:152)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.prepare(IndexCursor.java:96)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:154)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:475)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select$LazyResultQueryFlat.fetchNextRow(Select.java:1882)
    at org.h2.result.LazyResult.hasNext(LazyResult.java:101)
    at org.h2.result.LazyResult.next(LazyResult.java:60)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:742)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:884)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.queryWithoutCacheLazyCheck(Query.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:435)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:397)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:145)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:202)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:115)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 25 more
```

So I now have a way to use a native Connection object so can try a standard JDBC way

```
 public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs(StatelessSession session, List<Integer> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection connection = HibernateUtil.getSqlSession();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from SongDiff where recNo = ANY(?)");
            ps.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("Integer",  ids.toArray(new Integer[10])));
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                MainWindow.logger.severe(rs.getString("recNo"));
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

but this fails with

*java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;*

Not sure if this simply means c3p0 doesnt support this (but h2 does). However regardless I cannot update c3p0 to latest version but is there a different way to create an array that can be passed to the setArray() method ?

**Solution Update**
By using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290873/if-using-hibernate-with-database-and-c3p0-dbpooling-is-is-still-possible-and-s) to retrieve a jdbc connection and the advice in Evenijs answer I now have the following working method.

```
public static List<SongDiff> getSongDiffs(List<Integer> ids)
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = HibernateUtil.getSqlSession();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from SongDiff where recNo = ANY(?)");
            ps.setObject(1,  ids.toArray(new Integer[ids.size()]));
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            List<SongDiff> songDiffs = new ArrayList<>(ids.size());
            while(rs.next())
            {
                SongDiff sd = new SongDiff();
                sd.setRecNo(rs.getInt("recNo"));
                sd.setDiff(rs.getBytes("diff"));
                songDiffs.add(sd);
            }
            return songDiffs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to get SongDiffsFromDb:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            SessionUtil.close(connection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That thing with `AbstractMethodError` means your driver has no support for array types. Possibly it's an old version of the driver and you need by upgrading to newer version you could solve it.

Comment: thanks for updating your question with the solution. I ran into this exact problem today and now it is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JDBC you can use `… = ANY(?)` condition or `… IN(UNNEST(?))` condition in recent versions of H2 (in old versions a `TABLE()` function can be used instead as described in their documentation). H2 expects an array as argument (`Object[]` or `java.sql.Array`).

You should be able to use that feature with native SQL in Hibernate too.

Comment: Thanks confirmed H2 understands unnest but I cannot see how to pass the recnos as a dynamic parameter so can reuse prepared statement ?

Comment: With JDBC you should simply use `preparedStatement.setObject(1, new Object[] { … })`, with Hibernate you need to use `setParameter(1, new Object[] { … }, type)`, but most likely you will need to create a custom `type` for `Object[]` arrays on top of `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType` (can't confirm, I don't use Hibernate). Because you have a `java.util.List`, you also need to convert it to an `Object[]` with `toArray()` method.

Comment: It could be easier to use `Session.doReturningWork(…)`, the `ReturningWork` interface has access to JDBC features. If you use the embedded database, H2 will be able to cache and reuse the underlying command of `PreparedStatement` even if you can't cache the `PreparedStatement` itself (if you stay on the same `Connection` and you close the prepared statement after use).

Comment: With latest attempt the statement seems to run, but for some reason now unable to map the resultset ?

Comment: I fact cannot even extract resultset

Comment: With my last attempt Im just using pure sql (but constrained by an older version of c3p0) can I use alternative to createArrayOf

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help by getting a jdbc connection I now have a working solution.