# Apache Ignite IN query with parameters returns no results

Tags: java, sql, caching, ignite

I am trying to run a query on Ignite cluster which has IN clause. It is as below.

`SELECT _key,_val FROM ORDER_ERRORS WHERE ORDER_TYPES in (?) AND STATUS='OPEN' limit ? offset ?`

I am writing query code as below.

```
public List<OrderError> getOpenErrors(List<String> orderTypes, int offset, int limit) {
    SqlFieldsQuery sqlFieldsQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery(FIND_REC_QUERY);
    sqlFieldsQuery.setArgs(orderTypes.toArray(), limit, offset);
    FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> res = orderErrorsCache.query(sql);
```

This returns me 0 records. Now when I remove either orderTypes or limit and offset from that query. It returns me some records. But a combination of all 3 gives me nothing. Surprisingly I have a query before this, from which I obtain number of records for pagination. That query runs fine. Which is like below.

`SELECT count(1) FROM ORDER_ERRORS WHERE ORDER_TYPES in (?) and STATUS='OPEN'`

Now here there's a single parameter. And I run this query as below, and this works!

```
SqlFieldsQuery sqlFieldsQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery(TOTAL_REC_QUERY);
sqlFieldsQuery.setArgs(orderTypes.toArray());
logger.info("Finding record set size: {}", sqlFieldsQuery);
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> res = orderErrorsCache.query(sqlFieldsQuery);
```

What is going on here? What am I missing? Or is there something amiss with Ignite itself? Please help.

Ignite version: 2.9.0

Comment: your code will replace ? with '123,223,224,225' as complete string and will so not find a match.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlFieldsQuery` in Apache Ignite works more or less like a prepared statement. It looks like you are missing the part that there's only one placeholder in your query (that's why a single argument works). You need it to match with the argument array size.

In general a pretty similar question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives/10240302#10240302).

Comment: But I am providing 3 arguments and there are 3 placeholders indeed.